# Hibernate - difference between two dates

Tags: mysql, sql-server, hibernate, h2

How can I compute the difference between two dates, such that the query to be compatible with : MySql, H2 and SqlServer ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- SQL Server - you can use `DATEDIFF` function that returns difference in specified `DATEPART`

`SELECT DATEDIFF(dd,'1/20/2014,'1/22/2014')`

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx

---

- MySQL - `DATEDIFF()` just a little bit differently,

`SELECT DATEDIFF('2008-11-30','2008-11-29') AS DiffDate`

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff

---

- H2 - `DATEDIFF`

`DATEDIFF('YEAR', T1.CREATED, T2.CREATED)`

http://www.h2database.com/html/functions.html#datediff

Comment: Yes, I've already tried this, but MySql needs 2 params, and SqlServer(and H2) requires 3. But I would need the same query for both. is this possible?

Comment: MySQL uses only 2 parameters just like you mentioned. You can not make  same query run on all 3 platforms, you would need to modify your code to pass different query to each platform.

Comment: Yes. I think this is the only solution. :) Thanks

Comment: MySQL also supports [TIMESTAMPADD](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampadd) with 3 params. H2 supports this syntax as well.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server -

```
  datediff (day,startdate,enddate)
```